# How to create many cloud servers on behalf of many customers

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud, linode, cloud-hosting

I am trying to figure out a way to create cloud servers for customers that I wouldn't have access to.

For example, if I have 100 customers, I need some type of sign up process for the user to create a digital ocean, linode, etc, virtual instance that my company wouldn't have control over.

Once the instance is created, the customer would just have to run a simple install script to start using our product.

I am familiar with the Linode CLI but I don't think that would solve this problem.

The reason I need this is because my product has sensivtive log files and I don't want me or my employees to be able to see the log files of the customers.  Also, the customers are VERY non-technical.

We are just a small company and cannot expect people to "just trust us".

UPDATE
https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/easily-transfer-snapshots-between-accounts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing something like the [Azure Marketplace](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/) or [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace). I have no idea if Digital Ocean, Linode, or any of the other niche cloud providers have a similar platform, but there isn't a single answer that is applicable across every provider.